# Scroll table view cell to a particular CG Point

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

Hi has anyone tried to scroll a table view cell to a particular CG Point.

When we add the last product on a screen to the cart, the carousel should be added below it and scrolled slightly up, good enough to be visible. We have a floater view at the bottom, and hence we need to slide the carousel to a custom cg point.

EXPECTED: Scroll the carousel slightly up to make it visible
CURRENT: It's scrolled to the middle of the screen (using tableView.scrollToRow)

tableView.scrollToRow is not the best way as it has four options only (top, bottom, middle, none).

.bottom will not work as we have a floater view at the bottom.

Has anyone achieved something similar using tableview.setContentOffset?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use this method to scroll to a particular ract. ```UITableView().scrollRectToVisible(<#T##rect: CGRect##CGRect#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>)```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0,y :100), animated: false)
```